# Z80 assembly program gone haywire

Tags: assembly, z80

I am working on a small Z80 assembly program, one of my first.  Here is my Z-80 assembly code:

```
main:
        LD      SP, $FFFF            ; start by setting stack to top of RAM

printChar1:
        LD  A, 'X'                   ; this works
        CALL    transmitCharFromA    ; this works

        LD      HL, (generationMsg)  ; this does not work
        CALL    txAsciiZMsg          ; this does not work

endInNopLoop:
        NOP
        JR  endInNopLoop


generationMsg:  DEFB    "Generation: ", CR, LF, 0 ; null-terminated string
```

**The expected result is that it will output "XGeneration: " with a CRLF combination afterwards.**

The routine `transmitCharFromA` works great, and the first character of output is indeed "X".  Here is that routine:

```
transmitCharFromA:
        PUSH    AF              ; store char in A for later
consoleOutput:
        IN  A,($80)             ; read ACIA status byte       
        BIT 1,A                 ; set Z flag if still transmitting character       
        JR  Z,consoleOutput     ; and loop until flag signals ready
        POP AF                  ; get the character back from the stack
        OUT ($81),A             ; send it over RS232 to ACIA outpout address
        RET
```

As I mentioned this works great.  So I wanted to build on that by enabling the output of a null-terminated string:

```
txAsciiZMsg:
        LD  A, (HL)             ; A holds pointer to start of null-term string
        OR  A                   ; OR A with A to set Z flag if A holds null terminator
        RET Z                   ; return if done
        CALL transmitCharFromA  ; otherwise transmit it using working routine
        INC HL                  ; move pointer to next character
        JR  txAsciiZMsg         ; and keep going
```

This does not work, **outputting a bunch of garbage characters** before stopping and (ostensibly) going in to the `endInNopLoop` loop.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong in `txAsciiZMsg` routine that it is:

1. Printing garbage
2. Not printing the "Generation: " message
3. Not apparently finding the null-terminating 0x00 character

I am using z88dk to assemble and build my program.

I can see in my assembly listing that the `LD A, (HL)` statement is assembled right, showing the **first byte of the address of the message** as the operand to the LD instruction.  So I'm stymied as to what could be going wrong.

Can anyone point out my mistake(s)?

Comment: It has been far too long ago, but you need to load HL with the *offset* of generationMsg, not the content.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you Hans but maybe I phrased it poorly.  The LD (generationMsg) statement results in HL being loaded with the address of the first byte of the message, not the first byte of the message content itself.  I can see this in the assembly listing.

Comment: Are you sure about the logic that waits until it's ok to send? What happens if you remove it, do you get a different result?

Comment: @Sasq, I'm pretty sure of that logic.  In the program version before this one, I simply sent "X" to the terminal as fast as possible in an endless loop.  I think it's solid.  I copied this part of the routine from another working ROM-based program that uses serial communication, starting with it sending a single character because I was desperate to get *something* to print on the terminal.  That produced "X" characters really, really fast.

Comment: @TomServo Could you look at the hexadecimal opcode of the `ld HL,(generationMsg)` instruction again. I would have assumed instruction `2A` if it is written this way; Hans Passant obviously also does. However, you need instruction `21`. Instruction `2A` will get you nowhere.

Comment: @TomServo: `LD SP, $FFFF` leaves the last byte of RAM unused by the stack and any stack entry you push will be aligned at odd addresses. IMHO you would have used `LD SP, $0000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use:

```
LD   HL,generationMsg
```

to put the *address* of `generationMsg` into HL, instead of actually loading the contents with `(generationMsg)`, as Hans commented.

The correct assembly will show opcode `$21` instead of the opcode `$2A` you're getting now.  But in either case the address of `generationMsg` will appear so that won't serve as a way to distinguish correctness.

---

`LD   HL,(generationMsg)` is a load with an absolute direct addressing mode.  The instruction you want "loads" an immediate operand, and is totally different even though it shares the same mnemonic.